# convert hashtable.value to list<hashtable>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a HashTable content List when i want read content of this
  with code as follows :

```
Hashtable organCollection = new Hashtable();
Organ organ = new Organ ();
organCollection = organ.KMLDecode();
List<Hashtable> LinesCollection = new List<Hashtable>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in organCollection )
{
    LinesCollection = List <Hashtable> entry.Value;
}
```

and try as follows:

```
Hashtable organCollection = new Hashtable();
Organ organ = new Organ ();
organCollection = organ.KMLDecode();     
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
IDictionaryEnumerator en = organCollection.GetEnumerator();
while (en.MoveNext())
{
    string str = en.Key.ToString();
    arr = (ArrayList)organCollection[str];
}
```

But get following error:

```
Error   1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

I could not find solve
Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note - `ArrayList` and `HashTable` should be replaced with `List<T>` and `HashSet<T>`, respectively.

Comment: You can write `Organ organ = new Organ (); Hashtable organCollection = organ.KMLDecode();`

Comment: What problem in common are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... try this:

```
var organ_items = organCollection.OfType<OrganType>().ToArray();
foreach (OrganType item in organ_items)
{
    string str = item.Key.ToString();
    arr = (ArrayList)organCollection[str];
}
```

Here "OrganType" is a type of single element inside organCollection variable.

Comment: My OrganType is List<HashTable> when change as follows:  var organ_items = organCollection.OfType<List<Hashtable>>().ToArray();   after run organ_items is Null! –